# Show $\|f\|=\max _{[a, b]}|f(t)|+\max _{[a, b]}\left|f^{\prime}(t)\right|$ is complete set

Tags: normed-spaces, complete-spaces

Let V be the vector space of continuously differentiable functions on [a, b] with the norm
$$\|f\|=\max _{[a, b]}|f(t)|+\max _{[a, b]}\left|f^{\prime}(t)\right|$$ Show that V is complete.

I was trying to do so by taking an $f_n(t)$ and assuming it cauchy sequence, hence:

for $n,m>n_0$
$$max|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|<\epsilon$$
Now I just need to show that $f_n$ converge in the given norm.
$$\|f_n(t)-f_m(t)\|=\max _{[a, b]}|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|+\max _{[a, b]}|f'_n(t)-f'_m(t)|<\epsilon + \max _{[a, b]}|f'_n(t)-f'_m(t)|$$

How do I show that $$\max _{[a, b]}|f'_n(t)-f'_m(t)|<\epsilon$$

Comment: That's not what you want to prove. Take a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)$ for $\|\cdot\|$, you want to prove that $(f_n)$ converges towards a certain function $f\in V$ for $\|\cdot\|$. You instead took a Cauchy sequence for the norm $\|g\|_{\infty}=\max_{[a,b]}|g|$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien ok I think I understood my mistake, I know how to handle the first term by uniform converge. what should I do with the second term?

Comment: Let $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\|f_n-f_m\|<\varepsilon$ for all $n,m\geqslant n_0$, then $\|f_n-f_m\|_{\infty}<\varepsilon$ and $\|f_n'-f_m'\|_{\infty}<\varepsilon$ for $n,m\geqslant n_0$ therefore $(f_n)$ and $(f_n')$ are Cauchy sequences for the norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$. Now you can use the fact that $(\mathscr{C}^0([a,b]),\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ is complete...

Comment: I dont understand why is it trivial that also $\|f_n'-f_m'\|_{\infty}<\varepsilon$

Comment: Because for all $g\in V$, $\|g\|=\|g\|_{\infty}+\|g'\|_{\infty}$, thus $\|g\|_{\infty}\leqslant\|g\|$ and $\|g'\|_{\infty}\leqslant\|g\|$.